# How do I get OTA from I got last update np. Had no idea my s5active even had custom rom yesterday update failed "kernel" in red locked me out.

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, custom-roms, samsung-galaxy-s, locked-out, att

Ok  so I got a cool salesman who initially said my phone was bricked & tried 2 sell me a new phone. I explained I'm as broke as possible & was really upset about my phone not working!! Also I went from super happy (bcuz I thought I was getting marshmallow) to terrified bcuz my phone locked me out! He then got it working again but said DO NOT ACCEPT THE UPDATE. Or it will keep happening! This has me extremely upset being that I did not know or want custom rom on my phone. ESPECIALLY IF IT WAS GONNA BLOCK MARSHMALLOW! Plus what good is it if I never even knew it was there until yesterday! I've had the phone 4 a year at least!! If ANY1 can help me be able 2  get my update plz help! Ive been manually checking EVERY DAY, and constantly doing "android check ins" 2 try 2 speed up the process. I really just want my update! 
Thank you
-Joe

Answer (score 1):

The thing is AT&T's S5 Active doesn't have Marshmallow available yet, at least as far as my investigation goes. The best thing you can do is back things up, use Odin to reflash phone (to clean up custom ROMs and such) and try to check for updates again. You should at least be able to accept the update, but 1) it might just be a security patch and 2) since I don't own the phone, what will happen next is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks! The crazy thing is after all the locking me out & such the security patch still worked!? But if I flash it my custom message will be erased? Btw, my knox has not been triggered. Not sure if that helps? Thanks Andy

Comment: If you could accept the update (provided that it is legit) then nothing should be wiped. I'm not sure what the salesman means by telling you not to accept the update - if you bought the phone from AT&T and is still on the network then I don't see a reason why you shouldn't get the update via OTA.

Comment: ☆UPDATE☆Since this post I have received 2 OTA updates. Each time it paused at the very end.. showing only a black screen for about 15-30 seconds before showing the cogs & the "Android is working" message. I'm still getting the "custom" symbol at startup and recently have had difficulties using KIES. It's still a MYSTERY why that particular OTA security update caused my phone to say *kernel* in blue during the update. And then lock me out! I'm happy it hasn't happened again. But I really wish I could get rid of this custom thing!! There's NOTHING ON MY PHONE CUSTOMIZED!! 